# JSON with duplicate key names losing information when parsed

Tags: json, groovy

So either I go back and tell someone that they should fix their JSON, or I need to find out what I am doing wrong. Here is the JSON, notice that **parameter** occurs three times:

```
String j= '''{
    "jobname" : "test",
    "parameters" : {
    "parameter": {"name":"maxErrors", "value":"0"},
    "parameter": {"name":"case", "value":"lower"},
    "parameter": {"name":"mapTable", "value":"1"}
    }
} '''
```

And I am trying to get each name & value. My code

```
def doc = new JsonSlurper().parseText(j)
def doc1 = doc.entrySet() as List
def doc2 = doc.parameters.entrySet() as List
println "doc1.size===>"+doc1.size()
println "doc1===>"+doc1
println "doc2.size===>"+doc2.size()
println "doc2===>"+doc2
```

And my results:

```
doc1.size===>2
doc1===>[jobname=test, parameters={parameter={name=mapTable, value=1}}]
doc2.size===>1
doc2===>[parameter={name=mapTable, value=1}]
```

How come I only get one parameter?  Where are the other two? It looks like JSON only keeps one **parameter** and discards the other ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON is not in the correct format. There should not be duplicate key in the same hierarchy or they will override each other.

It should have been an array of paramters.

Like this,

```
String j= '''{
 "jobname" : "test",
 "parameters" : [
 {"name":"maxErrors", "value":"0"},
 {"name":"case", "value":"lower"},
 {"name":"mapTable", "value":"1"}
 ]
}
```

Comment: Good. This is the format I thought would be better and this is the format we'll use. Parses beautifully.